# jQuery, ajax 405 Method Not Allowed

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, http-status-code-405

I have a small "contact  form" with jQuery validation, PHP and ajax. My website running on IIS.

The problem is, I am trying to post the form contents using ajax + jQuery, but I am getting the response
like "**405 Method Not Allowed**" (From firebug console).

But its running properly in local server. Pls help me to fix 405 error. Thanks in advance.

Here's the JavaScript code while submitting the form:

```
$("#contactusForm").validate({

    rules: {
        firstName: {
            required: true
        },
        email: {
            required: true
        },
    },

    messages: {
        firstName: {
            required: " *Required"
        },
        email: {
            required: " *Required"
        },
    },

    submitHandler: function (form) {

        var dataString = 'firstName=' + firstName + '&email=' + email;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "send_contact.php",
            data: dataString,


            success: function () {
                $('#result').html("<br/><b>Thank you</b>");

            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: What server are you using? Apache? IIS?

Comment: Can you POST to that script from a normal web form?

Comment: Likely a data type issue...